# How to build COMPILE TestNG based framework without using Maven/Ant from a command line

Tags: selenium, testng

As you guys know junit & TestNG are testing frameworks, If you call TestNG.xml it will call the pre compiled classes, not the existing one.

If there any way to achive this with out using Maven or other build tools?

Comment: Maven is just a build tool that lets you compile your code, run tests, manage your classpath via dependencies. If you dont like to use Maven, then you can switch to using `Gradle` which is another build tool. But the biggest question here is, why do you not want to use Maven? What is your use case? Can you please edit your question and add more context ?

Comment: Have you tried by executing Testng.xml as suite ?

Comment: I mean to say that ! is there any provision such that we can compile the code, before executing the tests

Comment: @SiKing It is entire new concept. not a duplicate

Comment: I am not sure, Why the peoples are marking this question as a duplicate ? They are understanding the question.

Comment: Are you asking how to compile your code? If yes, you need to use `javac` - that is what the build tools call behind the scenes.

Comment: No. I have created a project in which jars are included {not maven}, I am calling the batch file which directly calls the testing.xml. here the test start executing. Is there any way we include something in testing.xml file such that before execution on tests, the code compiles.